# Create non-clustered index on the table variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I create a non-clustered index on the table variable below? I tried but it's throwing an exception

> Incorrect syntax near '@TBL'

My code:

```
DECLARE @TBL TABLE(ID INT PRIMARY KEY, FROMDATE DATETIME, TODATE DATETIME)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_myindex 
ON @TBL (FROMDATE);
```

Thanks

Comment: You can look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645210/sql-server-non-clustered-index-on-table-variable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to declare indexes within the table definition.  Although indexes are supported (since SQL Server 2014), the `CREATE INDEX` syntax does not support table variables.  So:

```
DECLARE @TBL TABLE (
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    FROMDATE DATETIME,
    TODATE DATETIME,
    INDEX idx_tbl_fromdate (FROMDATE)
);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=abcaa0024baeffb53aab8d835e96e039) is a db<>fiddle.

EDIT:

If you want a temporary table with an index, use a temporary table.  If your version supports this syntax, you can do:

```
CREATE temp_table (
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    FROMDATE DATETIME,
    TODATE DATETIME,
    INDEX idx_tbl_fromdate (FROMDATE)
);
```

Otherwise create the index separately.

Comment: getting "Incorrect syntax near 'INDEX'. If this is intended as a part of a table hint, A WITH keyword and parenthesis are now required. See SQL Server Books Online for proper syntax."

Comment: @user . . . As the answer specifies, explicit indexes in table variables are only supported since SQL Server 2014.  You are probably using an older version, which does not support this functionality.  In that case, just use a temporary table.

Comment: as per the duplicate you can create a unique constraint for this. `DECLARE @TBL TABLE (
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    FROMDATE DATETIME,
    TODATE DATETIME,
    UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED (FROMDATE, [ID]) 
);` this is the same index as `CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_myindex 
ON @TBL (FROMDATE); ` would create anyway if that syntax was allowed

Answer (score 0):

You can define `INDEX` in table variable defination :

```
DECLARE @TBL TABLE (
     ID INT PRIMARY KEY, 
     FROMDATE DATETIME, 
     TODATE DATETIME
     INDEX FROMDATE NONCLUSTERED
)
```