# Using Variable with function - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, user-defined-functions

I have custom function which return a table
it accepts two varchars, it splits the varchar based on the delimeter

```
SELECT VALUE FROM dbo.Split('xxx','_') --- working

select abc from abcd a,cde b where a.abc like (SELECT VALUE FROM dbo.Split(b.abc,'_'))-- not working


select abc from abcd a,cde b where a.abc like (SELECT VALUE FROM dbo.Split('xx','_'))-- working

select abc from abcd a,cde b where a.abc like (SELECT b.abc)-- working
```

How to get the not working case to work.

Error i get it
Incorrect syntax near '.'.

Comment: I'm sure you meant to ask a question as well ...?

Comment: What's the column type of abc from table b?

Comment: @MikaelEriksson he wants to know why that case isn't working, check the comments.

Comment: Can we see your code for `dbo.Split()` function

Comment: Mikael need to know how can i get the not working one to work...

Comment: It would help if you updated your question with some sample data that causes the error and please add the error message as well. I guess you are getting something like "Subquery returned more than 1 value.". Try to change `like` to `in` instead. It might do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [CROSS APPLY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156.aspx) allows you to use a variable as a parameter to a function.

```
SELECT abc
FROM   abcd a
       , cde b
       CROSS APPLY (select VALUE from dbo.Split(b.abc, '_')) f
WHERE  a.abc LIKE f.Value
```

or

```
SELECT  *
FROM    abcd a
        , cde b        
        CROSS APPLY dbo.Split(b.abc, '_') f
WHERE   a.abc LIKE f.Value
```

> The APPLY operator allows you to invoke a table-valued function for
>   each row returned by an outer table expression of a query.

**Test script**

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Split(@a VARCHAR(4), @b VARCHAR(4)) 
RETURNS TABLE 
AS RETURN
(
  SELECT Value = 'Test'  
)
GO

;WITH abcd (abc) AS (
  SELECT 'Test'
)
, cde (abc) AS (
  SELECT 'Test'
)  
SELECT  *
FROM    abcd a
        , cde b        
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT Value FROM dbo.Split(b.abc, '_')) f
WHERE   a.abc LIKE f.Value
```

Comment: SELECT *
FROM tablesxx c,tableyyy y
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 VALUE FROM dbo.Split(x.abc,'_')) f  WHERE x.abc LIKE f.value


Incorrect syntax near 'APPLY'.
Incorrect syntax near '.'.

Comment: @user1178514 - I've missed one `)`. The answer has been corrected.

Comment: Thanks alot. It works now..CROSS APPLY does not work because I am on SQL SERVER 2000...so I used another method which appraently you suggested http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644740/cross-apply-does-not-work-with-sql-server-2000

Comment: @user1178514 - It wasn't clear from your question that there was only one result returned but if it worked for you, you can mark this as answered and upvote my other answer :). See [How does accepting an answer works](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/)

Comment: Marked Answered...Can't upvote have got that much reputation yet...joined recently

Answer (score 0):

have you tried:

```
select abc 
from abcd a, cde b 
where a.abc like dbo.Split(b.abc,'_')
```

Comment: As the function returns a table when I call it like this it throws invalid object name error.